# Executing JS for a a specific div

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm trying to execute a js just for a specific div. I tried looking up some of the suggestions here on the site but I still can't get it to work.

I have a php script which also uses some js, when I run the script and load the js in the `<head>` everything works fine

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="../h1.php" type="text/javascript"></script></head>
<body> Content </body>
<html>
```

But I don't really want to execute the script for the whole body, I just need to run it for a div.

I tried as suggested in one of the posts:

```
<div id="11"> Content </div>
<script src="../h1.php" type="text/javascript"> 
oQuickReply.swap("11");
</script>
```

But that didn't work too as the js was not executed. Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: try `oQuickReply.swap("#11");`

Answer (score 4):

[`script` elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#the-script-element) can have a `src` attribute **or** content, but not both. If they have both, the content is ignored (the content is considered "script documentation," not code).

Use another script block

```
<script src="../hjs.php" type="text/javascript"> 
</script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    oQuickReply.swap("11");
</script>
```

Comment: this didn't work either.

I tird it this way
<div id="11">content</a>
<script src="../hjs.php" type="text/javascript"> 
</script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    oQuickReply.swap("11");
</script>

Comment: @user2334436 What exactly the function `swap` perform? And can you show its code?

Comment: @user2334436 I suppose the problem is in the execution of swap() it might perform the operation on body of page.Make sure that the param passed is used as target div.

Comment: @Satpal I'm using the php and js to build a function to hide some of the html code.

Comment: @Chakradhar Vyza I think thats exactly whats happening. The swap is performing the operation on body of page rather than just a div. When testing on a browser the pages looks blank, but When i view the source code everything is there. How can i make sure that the param passed is used as target div? or if there is another way to just run the js on a specific div? can you give me an example?

Comment: @user2334436 You should simply look into the swap method and change it so that the it will accept div id as param and do the operation on that div.